# Cannot cleanup OS X trash

Tags: macos, trash

OSX just won't let me clean the trash can.

I delete the "Previous System" folder (did it before a year ago and it worked just fine):

[image: trash can with Previous System folder in it]

But, when I try to clean it up, I got:

[image: alert saying file is in use]

I already rebooted and tried to clean it up using the command line, without success:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
Password:
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---: No space left on device
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---: No space left on device
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---: No space left on device
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---: No space left on device
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---: No space left on device
rm: : No space left on device
rm: /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System: Directory not empty
```

As you can see, it complains about disk space, but turns out I have a lot of free disk space, so this makes no sense to me.

What's going on here, and, most importantly, how can I fix it?

### EDIT

As asked in comments:

```
/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [0m[01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir3[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/

/Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---:
total 0
drwx------ 3 carlos wheel 102 Jul  7 20:50 [01;34mconfdir-14B---[0m/
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting it Terminal while booted from the [Recovery HD](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)? Also, be extremely careful using the `rm` command making sure you've properly typed the intended target correctly before pressing enter!

Comment: Try "Secure Empty Trash" from Finder menu. Have you tried "Verify Disk" and "Verify Disk Permissions" from Disk Utility?

Comment: Can you run `sudo ls -lR /Users/carlos/.Trash/Previous\ System/private/tmp/coreutils20150707-43005-1i8nk3t/coreutils-8.24` and paste the output here, please?  If the output is very long, give us the first 10 lines or so.  I think that `confdir-14B---` may be (hard?) linked to itself, so `rm` gets stuck in a loop whilst removing it.

Comment: @Ashley added the asked info... and indeed, seems like a hard link to itself. I ran Verify Disk but it didn't fix the problem...

Comment: Interesting! Ok, I'd suggest this: 1) look at the [inode numbers using `ls -li`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22406) -- if there is a cyclic reference, we should see the same inode number repeatedly; 2) BACK UP before trying any "fix", just in case; 3) [remove the file by inode number](http://superuser.com/a/143141/247574), using `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -inum [inode number] -delete`.

Comment: I seem to be suffering from the same issue. It's not quite a cyclic reference, but some kind of nasty corruption in the hard link library. I ran `ls -liR` and the inodes appear to be incrementing as I recurse, so removing by inode is doing nothing. Unless you have a better suggestion, I'm going to take a backup (excluding the `Previous System` directory to be sure…) and wipe the disk tonight.

Comment: @Ashley I tried that, no success. Same problem as zwaldowski :/

Comment: @zwaldowski @caarlos0 Ok, another idea. If there isn't a cyclic reference, there will be a finite number of `confdir-14B---` directories. I believe `rm` removes directories by going to the most deeply nested directory, removing all files there, then the directory, then ascending up to the next level and onwards to the top. So in the path `a/b/c/d`, the removal order would be `d`, `c`, `b`, `a`. In the shell, can you descend to the deepest level using `cd`, and try this manually? Or perhaps this is due to filesystem corruption as @zwaldowski suggests and backup/restore is the best option...

Comment: It doesn't seem finite. I used tab completion to descend and it just kept going… and going… and going… I'm pretty sure it's corruption. I try not to think about the similar horrors that probably hide in my backup disk's file system. ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem, and found a solution (can't post it as an answer though since the question is protected). I think the problem is that somehow the paths get to long for rm to handle properly. So I moved out the first ~20 layers of folders (mv conf+hitting tab a few times .) and then deleted the leftovers. After doing that for about 10 times everything was gone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get it it's obvious. 
Because you can't recurse deep down, you should move the directory which is one level deeper just one level up. After that a directory with depth "one" remains which can be deleted.

Lets assume you have an "infinite" directory a/a/a/a/a/a/a/....

then you do:

```
mv a/a b
rm -r a
mv b/a a
rm -r b
```

Repeat until no directory is left over.

Analogous to our "confdir-14B--" the following script works. (you have to press ctrl-c after it finishes)

```
while [ true ]; do mv confdir-14B---/confdir-14B--- b; rm -r confdir-14B---; mv b/confdir-14B--- confdir-14B---; rm -r b; done
```

Because the names are identical the scripts 'flips' between the original directory name and a temporary name. That is why two passes are needed.

Comment: Oh my, that was so obvious. Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Just happened this to me today, e.g. in my `~/.Trash/rcs-5.9.4/` i found many `confdir-14B---` recursively, e.g. `confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/confdir-14B---/...`

Because the simple `find . -depth ...` or the `rm -r` doesn't works, created the following shell script, which removes the recursive directories "upside down" one per one.

```
#!/bin/bash

err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

#recdir="confdir-14B---"
case $# in
1) recpath="$1" ;;
*) err "Usage: $0 /path/to/recursive_directory_name e.g. $0 ~/.Trash/somedir/confdir-14B--- " || exit 1 ;;
esac

[[ -d "$recpath" ]] || err "Directory $recpath doesn't exists." || exit 1
parent=$(dirname "$recpath")
cd "$parent" || err "Can't cd to $parent." || exit 1
recdir=$(basename "$recpath")

[[ -d "$recdir" ]] || err "Can't find $recdir in $parent" || exit 1
[[ -d "$recdir/$recdir" ]] || err "Directory $recdir in the $parent isn't recursive. The $recpath/$recdir doesn't exists." || exit 1

tmp="mvrm.$$"
[[ ! -d "$tmp" ]] || err "The $tmp exists. Can't continue" || exit 1
mv "$recdir" "$tmp"

n=0
while :
do
    [[ -d "$tmp/$recdir" ]] || break
    mv "$tmp/$recdir" .
    rmdir "$tmp"
    mv "$recdir" "$tmp"
    let n++
    echo "level $n done"
done

echo "level $(($n+1)) done"
rmdir "$tmp"
echo all done
```

Save it to somewhere (myself using the name `deeprm.sh`) and run it as:

```
bash script_name /path/to/recursive_dir_name
```

e.g.

```
bash ~/deeprm.sh ~/.Trash/rcs-5.9.4/confdir-14B---
```

**Warning: The script is dangerous! Don't use it if you don't understand fully how it works.**